# How to solve $3x + 8 = 4 \pmod{11}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a problem solving this. I can't get my head around on how to do it. Can anyone provide me with very basic step by step explanation?

Comment: https://wstein.org/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node18.html

Comment: Also this : http://gauss.math.luc.edu/greicius/Math201/Fall2012/Lectures/linear-congruences.article.pdf

Comment: So I think google can find you quite nice examples.

Comment: (1) subtract $8$ on both sides to get $3x=-4\pmod{11}$. (2) then do [Euclid's extended algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to obtain $a,b$ such that $3a+11b=1$. This implies that $3a=1\pmod{11}$. (3) Multiply both sides by $a$ to get $x=-4a\pmod{11}$. (4) If you want the final result to be a remaider modulo $11$, then finish it with dividing $-4a$ by $11$ to get $-4a=11q+r$, with $0\leq r\leq 11$. Then $x=r\pmod{11}$.

Comment: $3x\equiv{-4}\equiv {7}$ and $3^{10}\equiv 1$ so $3^{-1}=3^9=4$ Thus $x=6$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 
$$3x+8 \equiv 4 \pmod {11}$$

you can add $11$ to the RHS and subtract $8$ from both sides. In a congruence equation, you can add, subtract and multiply numbers just like how you do in a normal equation or inequality.
You can also add a multiple of the modulo number on any of the sides. This does not make a difference to your result.

So you get 
$$3x \equiv 7 \pmod {11}$$

Again, you can add 11 to the RHS to get

$$3x \equiv 18 \pmod {11}$$

In a congruence equation, you are allowed to divide both sides of the equation by a divisor which is coprime to the modulo number. For example, we can divide our equation by 3 on both sides as 3 and 11 are coprimes.

So we get

$$x \equiv 6 \pmod {11}$$

Or, you can represent this as $x=11k+6$, and the smallest number of this form is $11\cdot 0+6=6$.

Hope this helps :)